# Setting text in UIAutomator

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

I was just exploring the UIAutomator for Android app testing and came across this issue.

Based on the API.

https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator#screen-actions-of-the-device

I am trying to add a new contact programmatically as part of my exploration.

[image]

I have reached this page by using this code.

```
from uiautomator import device as d
d.click(x,y) #used to click all the way to contacts.
```

How do I insert text into the name textbox? Since I do not know the class image and there are not many examples on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `culebra` from [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to autogenerate the script that does it through a GUI.

Run

```
culebra -uG --scale=0.5
```

then you can touch on the `EditText` and enter the value

[image]

which is reflected on the device

[image]

While you do this, the script is automatically generated

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2014  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2015-08-19 by Culebra v10.7.1
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
#vc.dump(window='-1') # FIXME: seems not needed

vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise("u'Name'").type(u"My Contact")
```

Answer (score 4):

According to document, it should be

```
d(text="Settings").set_text("My text...")  # set the text
```

Comment: But that's provided the text box name is settings?

Answer (score 1):

Use `adb shell input text` instead.

Don't forget to import

`import os`

`os.system("adb shell input text "+ your_text)`

Answer (score 1):

I hope your exploration were doing well and funny :)
I see you have found an alternative to set the text. But there's an easy way to do it, something similar to the @Fang Wang answer, and I'll answer this for future researches about it.

```
d(text="Name").set_text("My text...")
```

This line above will works for sure. If you want to discovery the properties of any screen on Android you just need to use `uiautomatorviewer` and you will get something like that:

[image]

Then you will be able to inspect any screen element and discovery their details.

With these informations we can create our code to interact with any Android element.

In this case you need to use the text set on the field because the attribute class is the same for all fields.

Also you won't need to click on the fields if you specify the action you want and their name or class or resourceId etc...

PS: UiAutomatorViewer is installed with Android Studio.